# Restoring snapshot to new EBS volume in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm looking at creating a disaster recovery script on AWS for restoring servers.

I've written the Terraform script to create a new EC2 instance, but I'd like to restore a snapshot from the old EBS volume to a new one and then attach that to the new EC2 instance.

I've been looking through Terraform though and can't see a way to restore a snapshot to a new volume, is it possible?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with terraform, because once you've attached the volumes, you have to mount these and then copy over the data from the snapshot to the new EBS volume. Finally, unmount and detach the snapshot volume. I reckon that can be done with, say, Bash, but not terraform, as this is an IaC tool, not configuration management one.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer.  Following what you've said, it looks straight-forward with Ansible so I'll try that approach - I hadn't appreciated it being a config management issue because I was able to restore a DB snapshot using terraform, but it makes sense the way you described it